# Cast Object to MyType<T> where T can be any type

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, asp.net-4.5

I have some code that searches for all types of type `MyType<T>` in an assembly. `T` can be any type I use `Activator.CreateInstance` to create objects of these types. I need to pass these objects into a method that is expecting `MyType<T>` so I need to somehow cast each object from Object (returned by `Activator.CreateInstance`) to something of `MyType<T>`.

Comment: can you provide a code sample of what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: did the code below match your question and did it solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you need is a combination of GetGenericTypeDefinition - MakeGenericType combination to form your own new type. here is an example:

```
    public class  GenericTypeTest<T>
    {
        T value;
    }

    void MakeTest()
    {
        var newType = typeof(double);
        var customType = typeof(GenericTypeTest<object>).GetGenericTypeDefinition().MakeGenericType(newType);
        var createdObject = Activator.CreateInstance(customType);
    }
```

if you want to use that createdObject, it is a little complicated because you can't "hard code" anything:

```
    public class  GenericTypeTest<T>
    {
        public GenericTypeTest(T value)
        {
            this.value = value;
        }
        public T value {get; protected set; }
    }

    public void ShowSomething<T>(GenericTypeTest<T> genericContainer)
    {
         MessageBox.Show(genericContainer.value.ToString());
    }

    void MakeTest()
    {
        var newType = typeof(double); object newValue = 1.0;

        var customType = typeof(GenericTypeTest<object>).GetGenericTypeDefinition().MakeGenericType(newType);
        var createdObject = Activator.CreateInstance(customType, newValue);

        this.GetType().GetMethod("ShowSomething").MakeGenericMethod(newType).Invoke(this, new object[] { createdObject });
    }
```